# Question on Concatenation of Prime Numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, decimal-expansion

### Concatenation

[Concatenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation_(mathematics)) of two numbers $(p,q)$ in some number base is defined as combining the digits of those numbers, written as $p||q$ .

For example, $123||456=123456$.

Concatenation simply combines digits of two numbers.

---

### Concatenator

Let $p,q$ be prime numbers.

If the result of $p||q$ is a composite number, I call it the *Concatenator* of $p,q$.

If the result is a new prime number, then pair $(p,q)$ does not have a *Concatenator*.

**Always a *Concatenator*?**

From this you can see that all pairs of form $(p,2)$ and $(q,5)$ always have a *Concatenator*, since the result is divisible by $2$ for the first case and by $5$ for the second case.

Also, if $(|p-q|=2)$ and the smaller prime is $\gt3$, then the pair $(p,q)$ always has a *Concatenator* since the result [is always divisible by $3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2000873). These pairs are twin primes.

If $p=q$ then those pairs are also always a *Concatenator* of course.

**Perfect Concatenators**

I also wanted to mention that some pairs share the same Concatenator. If a pair $p,q$ has a unique Concatenator, then I call it the *Perfect Concatenator*.

Example: $37193$ is not a perfect one, since pairs $(3719,3)$ and $(37,193)$ and $(3,7193)$ all share it.

Example: Trivially perfect pairs are pairs where both $p$ and $q$ are one digit primes.

---

### Delayed Concatenator

Furthermore, if a pair does not have a Concatenator, we can multiply $p$ by $10$ before the concatenation, and check if the result is composite. If it is, the pair is a *Delayed-$1$ Concatenator*.

If the result is still not a Concatenator, multiply by $10$ again and repeat until you get a Concatenator. If you multiplied by $10^n$ in total, then the result is a *Delayed-$n$ Concatenator*.

> What is the most delayed concatenator?

---

Below are the smallest most delayed concatenators I've found so far for $p=2,3,5,7,11,13$

```
203, 20083, 200011, 200004133, 20000029, (5)

3013, 3007, 300011, 300002411, 30000089, (5)

5041, 500101, 50003, 500002237, 50000020063, (5)

703, 70043, 700019, 700002551, (4)

1107, 110071, 110003, 1100005879, (4)

13011, 130037, 130007, 130000307, 1300000457, (5)
```

Below are the smallest most delayed concatenators I've found so far for $q=2,3,5,7,11,13$

```
[doesn't exist] 

203, 29003, 50003, 27100003, 5527000003, (5)

[doesn't exist] 

1107, 3007, 130007, 103300007, 1069000007, 76810000007 (6)

13011, 230011, 200011, 857000011, 14990000011 (5)

3013, 190013, 15100013, 43000013, 4870000013 (5)
```

Where you see that the best I could find was a delayed $6$ concatenator.

The smallest $\text{D}6$ concatenator **so far** is $76810000007$.

This means $7681000007,768100007,76810007,7681007,768107,76817$ are all prime.

This is the result of concatenation of $(7681,7)$ by delaying it by $10^6$.

But the real smallest $\text{D}6$ would be of form $2000000||q$, if such $q$ exists.

---

> **Questions**
>
> - Can you find a more delayed concatenator? 
>   Is there such a thing as the **most-delayed-concatenator**?
> - Can a more delayed concatenator be computed/calculated without brute force search? 
>   Is it possible to define a more efficient
>     algorithm?
> - Is there anything similar to this already analyzed somewhere?
> - Are there any more trivial pairs $(p,q)$ such that they always have a concatenator, other than ones with $p=2,5$ and twin primes?

Asking if there is a delayed $n$ concatenator for some $(p,q)$ is like asking if there exists a sequence of prime numbers of length $n$ of form $$p||\underbrace{0\dots0}_k||q$$ 
for $k=0,1,2\dots n-1$.

Comment: I haven't ran any searches yet, but I have a hunch the OEIS covers this in excruciating detail.

Comment: @Mr.Brooks The only relevant sequence I found is the sequence of *Concatenators*: [A121609](https://oeis.org/A121609), but I haven't found anything that is similar to *delayed concatenators*.

Comment: Well, maybe that's something that needs to be added to the OEIS. I've thought of several sequences but I look them up and I find they're already in the OEIS.

Comment: is there an easy (read: algorithmically fast) way to tell if a pair $(p,q)$ does *not* have a concatenator?

Comment: @Tommy None that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $1,10,10^2,10^3,10^4$ and $10^5$ all have different remainders mod $7$. Thus, if neither $p$ nor $q$ is $7$, one of $p\|q,10p\|q,...,10^5p\|q$ is a multiple of $7$. So you can't get a delay of more than $5$ unless one of the primes is $7$.

Comment: And similarly for $17$, so you can never get a delay of more than $15$.

Comment: $90293$ is divisible by $7$, so that's a mistake.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Then something was wrong with my script, thanks for pointing this out.